# Adds a URL in the middle of the article when copied

Tags: jquery

So I plan to paste a specific url into the clipboard after copied content.
So the url will be right in the middle of the article, not at the beginning or end of the content. Example:

**Before copying:**

```
hello world..
hello world..
hello world..
hello world..
```

**After copying, the following content is saved on the clipboard:**

```
hello world..
hello world..
https://stackoverflow.com
hello world..
hello world..
```

Is there a way to do this using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, that's right, all content is copied, plus a certain url in the middle of the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in pure JavaScript.

When the button <kbd>Copy to clipboard</kbd> is clicked, a string containing the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the `div#content` is copied, including a link which is not visible in the DOM.

```js
const $contentDiv = document.getElementById('content')
const $insertLink = document.getElementById('insert-link')
const $copyBtn = document.getElementById('copy-btn')

var copyText = (textToCopy) => {
  const tempTextarea = document.createElement('textarea')
  tempTextarea.value = textToCopy
  document.body.appendChild(tempTextarea)
  tempTextarea.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
  document.body.removeChild(tempTextarea)
}

$copyBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  copyText($contentDiv.textContent)
})
```

```css
#insert-link {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  Lorem <br /> ipsum <br /> dolor <br />
  <a id="insert-link" href="https://stackoverflow.com">https://stackoverflow.com</a>
  sit <br /> amet.
</div>

<br />

<button id="copy-btn">Copy to clipboard</button>
```